# How can I tell which Latex (MikTex or TexLive) I have installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: miktex, texlive, ubuntu

I have installed TexMaker, and the compilation works.  But my memory is weak and I don't recall which Latex I have installed.  All this is too taxing on my memory...

Comment: Considering MikTeX is only available on Windows ... Or just run `pdflatex --version` in a terminal.

Comment: MikTeX is available also for Linux, but it is not packaged in any way. So you are 99.99% using TeX Live from Debian/Ubuntu. Your pdflatex --version call should show something like `pdfTeX 3.14159265 .... (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian)`. Another way to check is `dpkg -l texlive-binaries`, if the output starts with `ii` then you have TeX Live/Debian installed. And with `which pdftex` you can check one more thing: If it gives you `/usr/bin/pdftex` then you are using again TeX Live/Debian, otherwise you might have installed TeX Live from TUG directly.

Comment: Related: [pdftex - How to find out and interpret the LaTeX version number? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366586/how-to-find-out-and-interpret-the-latex-version-number), [distributions - Automatically Determine which TeXLive Version is being used - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96570/automatically-determine-which-texlive-version-is-being-used)

Answer (score 33):

Use

`pdflatex --version`

to tell which version of Latex you're using.

Comment: I see. You ask the question. You get an answer in comments and then you post that to get the credit for it? Do you really think this fair?

Comment: @cfr No, but in this case I don't care enough to write an answer of my own.

Comment: @cfr Not only is it fair, it is encouraged. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @cfr and besides the mentioned arguments, Torbjørn T. answered in the comments on March 8, Yan King Yin made this an answer in October! It is way simpler for other users to find and answer, which was written as an answer and it is also easier to see open questions. But Yan King Yin should now also accept his own answer, so the question is marked accordingly.