# Patch 2016 xparse to support k-type argument

Tags: macros, xparse, optional-arguments

As per [Xparse's new e-type argument (replacement for k-type argument)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345365/xparses-new-e-type-argument-replacement-for-k-type-argument), support for `xparse`'s `k_` argument type is no longer available as of TeXLive 2016 and thus have stuck to TeXLive 2015 so far.  I have *numerous* macros that are defined using the older `k_` arguments, so wondering if there is an easy patch that I can apply so that I can use the *new* version of `xparse` and still have the `k_` macros work.

I am willing to discard the `k_` and use the new `e_` but don't like the idea of changing all the macros at once and then having to debug where things went wrong.  If I have a single (patched) version of `xparse` that supports both argument types, the transition will be a lot easier. Also, in case I run into some issue with TeXLive versions newer than 2015, I need to be able to revert back to TeXLive 2015 until I resolve any issues.

The solution I have below is too cumbersome due to the number of macros involved. Having a patch would allow me to use both as I transition to using the `e_` argument types, and only revert to the solution below should I run into issues with newer versions.

### References:

- [Xparse's new e-type argument (replacement for k-type argument)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345365/xparses-new-e-type-argument-replacement-for-k-type-argument)
- [Automatically Determine which TeXLive Version is being used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96570/automatically-determine-which-texlive-version-is-being-used)

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
    %%  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96570/automatically-determine-which-texlive-version-is-being-used
    \def\getversion{\expandafter\get@version\pdftexbanner\@nil}
    \def\get@version#1201#2)#3\@nil{\def\TeXLiveVersion{201#2}}
\makeatother
\getversion


\ifnum\TeXLiveVersion<2016
    \NewDocumentCommand\MyMacro{k_}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
            \mathbf{A}
        }{%
            A_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
        }%
    }
\else
    \NewDocumentCommand\MyMacro{e_}{%
      \MyMacroProcess#1%
    }
    \NewDocumentCommand\MyMacroProcess{m}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
            \mathbf{A}
        }{%
            A_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
        }%
    }
\fi


\begin{document}

With a subscript: $\MyMacro_{\pi}$ 

Without any subscript: $\MyMacro$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't really want to test the version of texlive, rather the version of xparse eg `\@ifpackagelater{xparse}{2017/02/10}{this}{that}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yep, that would be a better test. However, I think the `k_` option type was dropped before 2017-02-10.

Comment: oh possibly, I just copied the date in the current version. It's probably not impossibly hard to locally add k back in addition to e but may be too hard to do just now, this evening:-)

Comment: But is there an explanation of why such a change was done without any transition period? Who decides? This change is causing a lot of troubles.

Comment: @gigabytes The `k` type (and indeed the `e` type) are explicitly experimental with _no certainty of retention_. The team need to have some scope to test out ideas which may turn out to be non-productive. That I know of, no code on CTAN used the `k`-type argument, so we judged that given the up-front warning it could be dropped. (Note that it's still not clear that `e`-type is right either: there remain issues which to some extent are shown in the two-part approach Peter has taken in his new code.)

Comment: I realize the feature was marked as experimental, and I don't question the team had the right to drop it. However, a transition period would have been useful. A version of xparse could have been released with both argument types and a warning issued for usages of the k-type. Later, the feature could have been removed completely.

Comment: I for instance had a paper not compiling anymore for a coauthor two days before a deadline. I could not debug the problem because I had an older version and I wasn't even aware of the change, so I only saw error messages that were senseless to me and that I couldn't reproduce. It took hours for me to realize what was happening, and days to understand how to replace the old code before the appearance of the question linked above, since the new documentation lacked even a single mention of the old k-type and how to switch. Things may have been gone better. Anyway, just my two cents.

Comment: @JosephWright: I realize the issues with experimental code, not suggesting that you need to retain backward compatibility (although would have been helpful for an interim period). I quite liked the `k_` parameter even with the limitation of a fixed ordering (ie, `_` before a `^`) so started using it.  The new `e` parameter does not have this order limit, but dislike it requiring the use of two macros. Anyway, those are my thoughts on it.  And, if the `e` is still subject to major revision, the patch is even more important for me so that I can hold off on the switch until things are stabilized.

Comment: @gigabytes The changes were made with the original idea of simply altering the behaviour of `k`-type: the change of identifier was a separate step. As I've said, we tend to look to what people have on CTAN to know when we need to be cautious: when people are using experimental features _directly_ in their documents, there is an expectation that they are competent to adapt as required. All that said, I will look to see if we can add `k`-type back in for the present.

Comment: @PeterGrill Indeed: we did argue quite a bit about this on the team. David in particular felt we need to stick to a 1-1 mapping, and I'm not entirely sure we've got it right yet (sorry). Please raise on LaTeX-L!

Comment: You can manually define `k`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245419/extending-xparse-for-new-arguments

Comment: @Manuel Yes but the internals have changed (to support `#` in optional args, for example): see my answer here!

Comment: @gigabytes One issue with any 'transition' period is that people _don't_ update their code _until it breaks_!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the current `xparse` release (`2017/12/16`), the following will re-add the `k`-type argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_if_exist:NF \c_novalue_tl
  { \tl_const:Nx \c_novalue_tl { \c__xparse_no_value_tl } }
\cs_if_exist:NF \__xparse_single_char_check:n
  { \cs_set_eq:NN \__xparse_single_char_check:n \__xparse_single_token_check:n }
\cs_if_exist:NF \__xparse_add_type_K:w
  {
    \cs_set_protected:Npn \__xparse_tmp:w #1
      {
        \cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_normalize_type_k:w ##1
          { \__xparse_normalize_type_K:w ##1 {#1} }
      }
    \exp_args:No \__xparse_tmp:w { \c_novalue_tl }
    \cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_normalize_type_K:w #1#2
      {
        \__xparse_single_char_check:n {#1}
        \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:nn {#2} { \__xparse_bad_arg_spec:wn }
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__xparse_arg_spec_tl { K #1 {#2} }
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__xparse_last_delimiters_tl {#1}
        \bool_set_false:N \l__xparse_grab_expandably_bool
        \__xparse_normalize_arg_spec_loop:n
      }
\cs_new_protected:Npx \__xparse_add_type_K:w #1#2
  {
    \exp_not:N \__xparse_flush_m_args:
    \exp_not:N \__xparse_add_default:n {#2}
    \cs_if_exist:NTF \__xparse_add_grabber:N
      { \exp_not:N \__xparse_add_grabber:N }
      { \exp_not:N \__xparse_add_grabber_optional:N }
        K
    \tl_put_right:Nn \exp_not:N \l__xparse_signature_tl { #1 }
    \exp_not:N \__xparse_prepare_signature:N
  }
    \cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K:w #1#2 \__xparse_run_code:
      {
        \__xparse_grab_K:NnNn #1 {#2}
          \cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn
          { _ignore_spaces }
      }
    \cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_long:w #1#2 \__xparse_run_code:
      {
        \__xparse_grab_K:NnNn #1 {#2}
          \cs_set_protected:Npn
          { _ignore_spaces }
      }
    \cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_trailing:w #1#2 \__xparse_run_code:
      {
        \__xparse_grab_K:NnNn #1 {#2}
          \cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn
          { }
      }
    \cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K_long_trailing:w #1#2 \__xparse_run_code:
      {
        \__xparse_grab_K:NnNn #1 {#2}
          \cs_set_protected:Npn
          { }
      }
    \cs_new_protected:Npn \__xparse_grab_K:NnNn #1#2#3#4
      {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__xparse_signature_tl {#2}
        \exp_after:wN #3 \l__xparse_fn_tl ##1
          {
            \__xparse_add_arg:n {##1}
          }
        \use:c { peek_meaning_remove #4 :NTF } #1
          { \l__xparse_fn_tl }
          {
            \__xparse_add_arg:o \c_novalue_tl
          }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\NewDocumentCommand\MyMacro{k_}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
      \mathbf{A}%
  }{%
      A_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

With a subscript: $\MyMacro_{\pi}$ 

Without any subscript: $\MyMacro$ 

\end{document}
```

---

I have raised the transition question with the team, and will either update the answer here on the next release (if required) or arrange for `k`-type to have some (limited) transitional support. Note though that this entire area is still very much in flux!

Comment: I am waiting for the `e` type paramater to be taken off the _experimental_ tag before replacing the older `k_` and `t_` arg types that I have used in numerous macros.

Comment: @PeterGrill That may _never_ happen: the whole point of `xparse` is to allow some experimentation. What I can say is we won't be going back to `k`.

Comment: @PeterGrill We have a whole question of what to do with the non-LaTeX2e-like ideas: they work but do they encourage the wrong approaches (see the `g`-type for example).

Comment: So, I guess I might as well stick to the `k_` type then.

Comment: I agree with the `g` type macro possible leasing to problems. But, I actually found a good use of the `g` type parameter. When I add a new mandatory parameter to a macro, I initalyy use the `g` type so that I can easliy detect older uses of it until I get around to updating all uses of the macro. Then chnage the `g` to an `m`.

Comment: I've updated my answer for TL'19 `xparse`, but really i would recommend looking to use the newer, stable, `e`-type argument.

Comment: Seems to work great. Will test further. Is the `e`-type no longer considered experimental?

Comment: @PeterGrill There are no plans for removal of any `xparse`  types: we've reached an equilibrium. So I'd assume all are stable.

Comment: The newest relase seems to have to broken something related to this -- but as _not_ asking you to update the answer. I decided it was time to go through and replace _all_ instances of `k_` with `e{_}`. As I was doing this I encoutered a case where I needed to check the documentation and noticed that `e{}` is still marked as _experimental_.  Does this mean that that the documentation was not updated, or that this option is indeed in danger of being removed or altered so that it is not backward compatable?

Comment: @PeterGrill We moved almost all of `xparse` to the LaTeX2e kernel, which means that it's all now stable.

Comment: Page 3 of the 2023-01-16 documentation of `xparse` still lists the `e` type as _experimental_. Surprisingly, this is not mentioned for the `E` type parameter.  Is `e` really _still_ experiemntal, or just a documentation issue? If the later, can this please be corrected in TeXLive 2023.  If it is still experimental, would it be safer to use the `t` type parameter for parsing optional `_` and `^` parameters as that seems to work.

Comment: @PeterGrill The stable part of `xparse` has been moved to the kernel and is now documented in `usrguide`. That includes the `e` specifier. Not that `t` and `e` are rather different: `t_t^` would not allow `\foo^{a}_{b}`, whereas `e{_^}` does.

Answer (score 4):

For the simple case where it is used with a single token `e` and `k` are more or less the same so if you just make `\IfNoValue` a little less fussy abut the difference between `{-NoValue-}` and `-NoValue-` then you can alias `k` to `e` if it's not already defined so your MWE drops down to:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ifx\__xparse_normalize_type_k:w\undefined
  \def\__xparse_normalize_type_k:w{\__xparse_normalize_type_e:w}
  \let\xIfNoValueTF\IfNoValueTF
  \def\IfNoValueTF#1{\expandafter\xIfNoValueTF\expandafter{\@car#1.\@nil}}
\fi
\ExplSyntaxOff


    \NewDocumentCommand\MyMacro{k_}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
            \mathbf{A}%
        }{%
            A_{\textcolor{red}{#1}}%
        }%
    }

\begin{document}

With a subscript: $\MyMacro_{\pi}$ 

Without any subscript: $\MyMacro$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Clearly Joseph's answer is the more complete fix but I'll leave this one here for the "one line" case which might be easier to understand than the full `k` implementation. (But you should accept Joseph's answer:-)

Comment: FYI, This works fine in the MWE, but it did _not_ work in my actual use case.  I guess my usage must be more than just the basic case.