# Which exact versions of `xparse` changed the behavior of `k`-type and `e`-type arguments?

Tags: xparse

At some point in 2016 the `xparse` package changed its `k`-type argument to the better `e`-type one. Then, shortly after, the behavior of the `e`-type arg was changed again to improve its usability.

This is described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345365/xparses-new-e-type-argument-replacement-for-k-type-argument).

Now, I'm writing a class that defines some commands using `e`-type args and I would like to be compatible with whichever version of `xparse` one might have. Notably, *arXiv* runs TeXLive 2016 with a version of `xparse` that seems to support the *old* behavior of `e`-type args, so this is an important case to consider.

Thus I would like to use `\@ifpackagelater` in my code to detect which kind of arguments I have to use and define my macros accordingly. However, I have troubles finding the exact versions (*i.e.* the date to give to `\@ifpackagelater`) to discriminate the two changes, *i.e.* from `k`-type to `e`-type, and from the old to the new behavior of `e`-type.

Which are the dates of those changes, suitable to give to `\@ifpackagelate` for this purpose?

**UPDATE**: To clarify my need. What I want to do is to write class code supporting TeXLive 2016 onward, because that's what arXiv runs, and this means I have to:

1. gracefully exit if the xparse package is too old (by providing the correct date to `\RequirePackage`) and
2. discriminate between the two behaviors of `e`-type to support both (by providing the correct date to `\@ifpackagelater`

So I need the dates of the two changes.

Comment: You know that the `k`-type was explicitly experimental? Would you not be best simply writing code that doesn't use this area? Alternatively, have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357187/patch-2016-xparse-to-support-k-type-argument/357247? You could add that then use `k` throughout ...

Comment: Yes, I know `k`-type was experimental, and I didn't like it so it's fine. I'd prefer using modern `e`-type args but, as said, arXiv doesn't support it, and that's a pretty important use case to consider. An alternative would be to write the same things parsing the args manually but then I'd just drop using `xparse` altogether...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change was made in `xparse` on 2016-11-18 in commit [b5adad3cd](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/b5adad3cd):

```
commit b5adad3cd26cf518099611baa4e8f6ea8f80ed0b
Author: Joseph Wright <joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk>
Date:   Fri Nov 18 20:22:43 2016 +0000

    Switch from "k"- to "e"-type
```

although there were then a few more commits to get everything right. This code was sent to CTAN with release string [`2016-11-21`](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/releases/tag/2016-11-21) replacing previous version [`2016-10-19`](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/releases/tag/2016-10-19), which still contains the old code.

---

The breaking change in `e`-type behaviour which then followed is in commit [94411cca7](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/94411cca7):

```
commit 94411cca7b70dbbd634ee42846e36039143aad87
Author: Bruno Le Floch <blflatex@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Apr 12 17:46:46 2017 +0000

    Make xparse e-type give separate arguments (see #226, #331) (breaking change)

    This avoids requiring an auxiliary to use the output of e-type arguments. The
    current "e{^_}" has a behaviour similar to the old "k^k_" (but allowing arbitrary
    order) but quite different from the previous version of e-type arguments.
```

The first release containing this is [`2017-05-13`](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/releases/tag/2017-05-13); the last one with the first attempt at `e`-type is [`2017-04-01`](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/releases/tag/2017-04-0).